# Keycloak - Log user without password

Tags: python, keycloak

Im using Keycloak to manage User Login.
I have a Software that redirect to Keycloak Login if user is not Logged.
Normal login by username and password works fine.

I need to support some "italian identity system" that are not covered with plugins yet.
So I was thinking to managed that kind of login whithin my software and then, after I have trusted the user, log in it in Keycloak using API.

Im using Python Keycloak to manage comunication between my software and Keycloak.

So I need a way, maybe using an "admin account" to force an autentication of a user having only his username because external Identity Manager has already trusted him.

Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question. If I'm mistaken, please include your relevant code.

Comment: "Is there a way?" I don't know, probably yes. Well that was your question and my answer. hope it helps

Comment: Not really. I was hoping in a more implemented answer but thank you for answering me.